# How to color circles depending on the number of items in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to create a grid of circles. The color of each circle comes from a dictionary of colors.

```
circle_colors_dict = {0 ['#7CB9E8', '#00308F', '#72A0C1', '#1CAC78']
                      1 ['#fd5c63', '#FBCEB1', '#A52A2A', '#FF7F50']
                      2 ['#F0E68C', '#FFC72C', '#87A96B', '#4B6F44']}
```

```
def draw_shapes(circles, start_x, start_y, circle_colors_dict, size, num_rows):
    num_colors = len(circle_colors_dict[0])
    y = start_y       
    for row in range(num_rows):
        x = start_x
        for col in range(num_rows):
            row_num = num_rows % num_colors            
            ....
            ....
            rect = a_canvas.create_oval(x, y , x+size, y+size, fill=color)
            x += size
        y += size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you initialize `circle_color_dict` in a wrong way (syntax error).

Second you calculate the row index in a wrong way.

Below is modified `draw_shapes()` to fix the issues:

```py
# actually you can use list of list instead
circle_colors_dict = {0: ['#7CB9E8', '#00308F', '#72A0C1', '#1CAC78'],
                      1: ['#fd5c63', '#FBCEB1', '#A52A2A', '#FF7F50'],
                      2: ['#F0E68C', '#FFC72C', '#87A96B', '#4B6F44'],
                      3: ['#DDA0DD', '#662d91', '#E6E6FA', '#EE82EE']}

def draw_shapes(circles, start_x, start_y, circle_colors_dict, size, num_rows):
    num_colors  = len(circle_colors_dict) # number of color rows
    y = start_y
    for row in range(num_rows):
        x = start_x
        row_num = row % num_colors # cater roll-over of row number
        color_cnt = len(circle_colors_dict[row_num]) # number of colors in current row
        for col in range(num_rows):
            color = circle_colors_dict[row_num][col%color_cnt] # cater roll-over of column number
            rect = a_canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+size, y+size, fill=color)
            x += size
        y += size
```